bldc motor with hall effect sensor
I have bldc motor.I just powered up the hall effect sensors by connecting 5v to my stm32 dev board and also connect the ground pin. and then I checked the voltage on output pins while rotating the motor by hand . and each pin give 0v all the time.
what is the issue ? how I can solve it ?

You should post this on Electronics Stack Exchange. It doesn't sound like a software problem.

What type of sensor is used? Probably you need a pull-up resistor on the output.
